# SQL Server : select the top 3 items from the top 3 categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to receive a single data set of the top 3 items from the top 3 categories.

The top categories would be ordered by a sum of the ItemScore column descending grouped by category, for example, Category 1 has a score of 23, Category 2 has a score of 22.

Each item in that category is then ordered by its ItemScore descending.

Here is a list of the raw data.

[image: Raw Data (Image)]

And here is an example of the expected result.

[image: Expected Result (Image)]

I hope this makes sense!

UPDATE:

Here is a script I have been working with and some test data;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
    [CategoryName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NULL,
    [ItemName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemScore] [int] NULL
)

INSERT Test (CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemID, ItemName, ItemScore) 
VALUES (1, 'Category 1', 1, 'Item 1', 1),
       (1, 'Category 1', 2, 'Item 2', 2),
       (1, 'Category 1', 3, 'Item 3', 7),
       (1, 'Category 1', 4, 'Item 4', 1),
       (1, 'Category 1', 5, 'Item 5', 1),
       (2, 'Category 2', 6, 'Item 6', 1),
       (2, 'Category 2', 7, 'Item 7', 1),
       (2, 'Category 2', 8, 'Item 8', 9),
       (2, 'Category 2', 9, 'Item 9', 10),
       (2, 'Category 2', 10, 'Item 10', 2),
       (3, 'Category 3', 11, 'Item 11', 1),
       (3, 'Category 3', 12, 'Item 12', 1),
       (3, 'Category 3', 13, 'Item 13', 2), 
       (3, 'Category 3', 14, 'Item 14', 1),
       (3, 'Category 3', 15, 'Item 15', 2),
       (4, 'Category 4', 16, 'Item 16', 5),
       (4, 'Category 4', 17, 'Item 17', 6),
       (4, 'Category 4', 18, 'Item 18', 3),
       (4, 'Category 4', 19, 'Item 19', 5),
       (4, 'Category 4', 20, 'Item 20', 1),
       (5, 'Category 5', 21, 'Item 21', 2),
       (5, 'Category 5', 22, 'Item 22', 8),
       (5, 'Category 5', 23, 'Item 23', 5),
       (5, 'Category 5', 24, 'Item 24', 3),
       (5, 'Category 5', 25, 'Item 25', 4)

SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CategoryID ORDER BY t.ItemScore DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM 
    Test t
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote a post then have the intestinal fortitude the state your reason #SomePeopleSmh #Cowards

Comment: You will get a better support from the community if you show what you've tried or how you've attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Kane for your feedback - I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

- first calculate the `CategoryScore` (the sum of `ItemScore` per category)
- then, add "ratings" for categories and items according to their score
- last, return only those records where both ratings are at most 3:

Putting that in a query, it could look like this:

```
WITH
  summing AS (
    SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemID, ItemName, ItemScore
      , SUM(ItemScore) OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID) AS CategoryScore
    FROM Test
  ),
  rating AS (
    SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemID, ItemName, ItemScore
      , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CategoryScore DESC, CategoryID) AS GrpNumber
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY ItemScore DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM summing
  )
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemID, ItemName, ItemScore, RowNumber
FROM rating
WHERE GrpNumber <= 3
  AND RowNumber <= 3
ORDER BY GrpNumber, RowNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the query to be a subquery, then get RowNumber `1` to `3`

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      Row_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CategoryID ORDER BY t.ItemScore DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM Test t
) t1
where RowNumber <=3
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=acac6f028458338f0727d82fbe437259)